# Mapas y medir distancia a markers fijos

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

necesito generar un mapa con puntos fijos son x puntos.  y necesito que al ingresar una dirección me diga que punto es el mas cercano y me los ordene.

básicamente necesito algo similar http://www.cbs.cl/contenido/Noticiasgaleria/247/portada_247.jpg

Comment: Me parece estupendo! Cual es el problema que te estás encontrando que llevas hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Debieras dividir el problema en etapas. 1) saber cómo encontrar la distancia entre un origen y un destino fijos. 2) cómo obtener las coodenadas de origen ingresando una dirección. 3) cómo hacer el paso 1)  cuando uno el oriden es ingresado por el usuario mediante el paso 2). Cuarto, iterar el paso 3) para el caso de N destinos. ¿Es para bomberos?

Comment: si la idea es generar algo similar al sistema commander. pero pensando en cuerpos de bomberos mas chicos.

Comment: Bueno, podrías empezar replicando el ejemplo de https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=es-419 para Santiago. Con eso ya tendrías resuelto el punto 2